# How to run code/endpoint once when next.js server started?

Tags: next.js, next.js13

How to run code once when next.js server started, fetch endpoint after app started?
I use next.js 13.5.4 and docker with `output: "standalone"`.

Instrumentation doesn't work (starting after hand open localhost:3000) it is any solution?

I try:

- in dockerfile:
  `CMD ["node", "server.js", "&","curl", "http://localhost:3000", "&", "wait"]` - not work